# What is the use case for "Github Pull Request allowed to be modified by maintainers"?

Tags: github, request, pull

Why did GitHub allow maintainers to be able to modify pull request?
What is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

The use case is that sometimes there is a small issue like a typo or style fix, and it's easier for the maintainer to modify the commit or apply an additional commit and push to that branch than it is to ask the user to fix their commit message or amend their commit to remove trailing whitespace, especially if the user doesn't have good skills with `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`.  Another use case is to add a tricky test for a PR that lacks one when the original author may not be familiar enough with the codebase to write a good test.

However, other folks sign commits, so a modification to the commit would necessarily cause the signature to be removed, so some people prefer to disable it.  Still others are comfortable with rebasing and squashing in changes and would prefer to make those changes themselves.